# Can the passwords in cakephp be un-hashed?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently hashing all of my users passwords and putting them into my database.

Now some of my users wants me to get their password or want me to do some admin stuff while logged in as them.

My question is can i unhash the password stored in the database and retrive it? and if so how ?

is there a function in cake that allows this feature?

Comment: That is called **encryption**.. **Hash** is a one-way road... (however, you can probably use a rainbow table to crack it, if there is no salt... At least MD5 semms to be well-rainbowed...)

Comment: well is there anyway to decrypt it then?

Comment: @Marc hash (which is likely what cake uses) is one way there is no way to dehash it...
You could write a script to reset the password if forgotten but that's about it for them asking.

Comment: Marc: NO. Hash is for hashing. You can not get the original value back with a defined algorithm.

Comment: @Marc: how I'd do this, if there is no salt: 1. save the hash of the user to be impersonated 2. copy over a hash of a known password 3. log in using **the known password** 4. copy back the original hash. If there is salt, you have to copy and revert the salt too!

Comment: @ppeterka66 Encryption is categorically *not* hashing, they are two totally different things. In response to the OP, you cannot reverse a hash; that’s the whole point of a hash.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Sorry. I thought you were suggestion hashing and encrypting were interchangeable terms. My bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Hashes cannot be reversed by design. You can find collisions, but that’s not reversing a hash.

If you need admin-level access then build it into your application. But a user’s password should not be recoverable. If someone gains access to your database and your users’ passwords *are* recoverable, then you’ve failed as a developer and compromised every user of your application.

Comment: Good answer, exactly what I was about to post.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that they forgot their password means that you can give them any password, so my advice for that would be to simply generate a new password comprising of a pronounceable word and a few numbers and send that to the user; they can change their password afterwards, anyway.

This way you don't have to compromise on security, because password hashes aren't meant to be reversed in the first place.

Impersonating users is an administrative feature; if you have the proper roles you can become another user and do things as them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "unhash" something, that's why hashing is "secure" (we won't go into debate here).

Now, why would your users want to get their password back? Because they forgot them and can't log in? If that's the case, there's other ways to do the "forgot password, I'll fix that for you" other than trying to unhash something. Most common are to place a "forgot password" link that ask for the email, sends an email with a link to reset the password, the user clicks the link and the reset creates a random password (and hashes it) replacing the old one and sends the new random pass to the user, the user use the random pass and can change it for a new one when logged in the application.

If you, as admin, want to do something as "act as" someone else, you could add a function (that only you as admin have access) that let you "act as" another person, without knowing their password. It depends on what you want to do exactly what the best solution for this would be and that should be posted as an entirely different question, I think.

But, please consider this carefully, it's a very very dangerous thing to do. What if someone can execute this function? Isn't there other solution? If you do this, the only thing between an attacker and the entire access to every account in your application would be your admin password. If you change the password hashing to a password encryption (that *can* be reversed and obtain the plain text), then some "evil" will have a much easier time to decrypt the passwords too. I know the client has the last word, but explain to him, *it is very insecure to do what he wants*.